# Facebook signup button redirects to broken link "r.php"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I have implemented facebook like functionality  in my site, for non facebook users it provides "signup" button. Clicking on signup button it shows a campaign page link(http://www.facebook.com/campaign/landing.php?campaign_id={Some id}&partner_id&placement=activity_plugin&extra_2=IN), which then redirecting to a broken link "r.php".

Anybody having idea why its happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a Facebook issue. There is an open bug regarding this issue:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/638872986135523

Last update was that they were looking at (14 November 2013).